# Common Javascript/CSS/HTML recipe book

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just wondering if there is a good 'recipe' book that has compiled all/most of the common design templates and features in the front layer of web development? Does such a book exist?

Just to name a few examples would be:

1. Save dialog box
2. Continuous scrolling
3. Model window pop-ups
4. Different page layouts etc

Thanks

Comment: check out these links, [ebook
](http://ebookee.org/dl/cookbook-css-html/) [http://blog.reybango.com/2010/04/29/the-big-list-of-javascript-css-and-html-development-tools-libraries-projects-and-books/](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/04/29/the-big-list-of-javascript-css-and-html-development-tools-libraries-projects-and-books/) [link for ebboks](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Common%20Javascript/CSS/HTML%20recipe%20book&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=ZYO&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=ivnsb&source=univ&tbm=bks&tbo=u&ei=ID2oTZu7JMLsrQf9uP2nCA&sa=X&oi=book_group&ct=title&cad=bottom-3results&resnum=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what are you looking for from Amazon.com :

[Pro CSS and HTML Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598040)  // but you may download it from any where else

and

[APress_ProJavaScriptDesignPatterns](http://bheinrichs.nl/Files/design%20patterns/APress_ProJavaScriptDesignPatterns.pdf)

these are the best you can find.

Answer (score 0):

More than common design templates, I will say, best design patterns. One of the best books I read so far is from the Filament Group:

Designing with Progressive Enhancement
http://www.filamentgroup.com/dwpe/

And they provide real working examples.